# How to say "if you eat too saltly, it is unhealthy to you" in Japanese using"塩辛い(しおからい)"

Tags: translation

If you eat too saltly, it is unhealthy to you

- using"塩辛い(しおからい)"

？：
あなたがあまりにも塩辛い食べるなら、それはあなたに不健康です

？：
もしあなたが食べるのが塩辛いなら、体によくないです。

Comment: Hello and welcome to Japanese.SE! Our policy about translations is that you have to give the translation a try yourself. Then people can improve on your translation (if necessary).

Comment: ありがどうございます。わかりました。

Comment: The first translation is copied verbatim from Google Translate. Is the second one your own?

Comment: Although it's understandable, the English is slightly awkward. At a guess, is your native language neither English nor Japanese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways to say that. Off the top of my head:

> - [塩分]{えんぶん}の[摂]{と}りすぎは、[体]{からだ}に[悪]{わる}いです。/ 体に[良]{よ}くありません。
> - [塩辛]{しおから}いものを[食]{た}べすぎると、体に悪いです。/ 体に良くありません。
> - しょっぱい*ものを食べすぎると、体に悪いです。/ 体に良くありません。
> - 塩辛いものの食べすぎは、体に悪いです。/ 体に良くありません。
>     etc...

*しょっぱい is a colloquial version of 塩辛い.